# phplist api - subscibe / edit / remove users by ajax

Tags: ajax, mailing-list, phplist

I have a very-simple php-based website.
I would like to add "subsribe for information" box and send it to some list-management tool.
I found that [phplist](http://www.phplist.com/) is quite a good one. However, I don't find any api which allows me to subscribe users using ajax.
(I would like to avoid the pages of phplist in order to avoid confusion due to different design, and also I want the interface to be multi-language).

Of-course I can touch the code, but I doubt that it misses this feature, so I assunme I simply missed it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Hopefully you have managed how to achieve this already. I have a different use case not requiring AJAX.

Anyway, I've found a script that tries to ease the addition of subscribers to your list. Maybe you could use it as the backend to support your AJAX request.

This is the thread in which the script is shared, as others have found it useful, also for unsuscribing users, even handling massive subscriptions/unsuscriptions:

http://forums.phplist.com/viewtopic.php?t=5009

Finally, be aware this code is using PEAR DB abstraction layer, probably I'm going to use this but without the PEAR package.

I look forward for what you could do through AJAX and this functions.